# NullPointerException in WorkbenchPage.busyShowView

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho, e4

I have a simple view registered normally in my Eclipse plug-in (4.5.2), and it works when I start an Eclipse instance with the plug-in. It still works in the corresponding test case, which has the following method:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    IWorkbenchPage activePage = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    for (IViewReference viewReference : activePage.getViewReferences()) {
        activePage.hideView(viewReference);
    }
    activePage.showView("org.acme.MyView");
}
```

Yet when I run the same test with Tycho (0.22, 0.24 or 0.25), I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4234)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4214)
    at org.acme.MyViewTest.setUp(MyViewTest.java:39)
```

The Tycho code is simple:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <providerHint>junit4</providerHint>
        <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488719) and a couple more, but I found nothing explaining why it would only fail in Tycho. And I couldn't find anything on how to fix this.

So what did I do wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that something is missing in your test runtime that’s required by the full-blown Eclipse workbench and which PDE adds, but Tycho doesn’t. (By default, Tycho only adds the (transitive) dependencies of your `eclipse-test-plugin` to the test runtime.)

Try adding the following to your `tycho-surefire-plugin` execution:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... ->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.e4.rcp</artifactId>
      <type>eclipse-feature</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</configuration>
```

This should pull a lot of plugins into your test runtime that may not be present otherwise (like `org.eclipse.e4.core.di`, which tests normally don’t depend on directly or indirectly).

Of course, the above only works if the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature is part of your target platform.

Comment: Had the same problem, solution worked at first try. Thank you very much!